# Display result after 15 minuts from date and time field php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on booking website. I've booking table with `date_created` and `time_created` field. I am storing todays date as `date_created` and current time as `time_created`. I want to list the booking after 15 minutes of `time_created` in admin panel. How this can be done?

I'd tried this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_booking
WHERE (date_created = '$todaysdt'
       AND time_created >= '$timenow')
  OR (date_created < '$todaysdt')
ORDER BY booking_id DESC
```

but this not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're checking to see if the time it was created is greater than (after) the current time? Don't think that's gonna work out very well...

Comment: I am not good in mysql sir. can you please help me writting correct query here?

Comment: No, I really can't, because I would have to assume too much about your database schema.  If I were doing this, I wouldn't have two separate fields for date and time; I would use a datetime field (mysql has that, right?).  That being said, you want to display records that are 15 minutes old or more.  So to do that, you would get records that the datetime is less than current time minus 15 minutes.  See PHP DateTime class or strtotime to figure out current time.  One other thing-- look up placeholders for your query; you shouldn't put variables into the query

Comment: i would've also combine both the fields in one field as date time but it is the requirement of client to have both in seperate fields. Thanks for your help

Comment: Many things can be blamed on requirements, but slavishly letting users design databases isn't a "requirement". It is technicians who design the technical solution in response to user requirements. The technician got this bit wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
select *
from tbl_booking
where STR_TO_DATE(concat_ws(date_created," ",time_created),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
order by booking_id desc
```

Comment: i can't do that sir. It is requirement of a client to store both in seperate fields

Comment: can you give me some sample data of what you hold in both of those fields?

Comment: in date_created i am storing Y-m-d format date and in time_created H:i of date function

Comment: Okay, the query has been updated and i was able to test on some mock data. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I am sorry, but are you literally storing the date as a string (Y-m-d) and time (H:i) as another string? **That would be a disaster.** I'm sure disasters are not a requirement. In fact avoiding disasters is. Go back to whoever told you to do it and make them understand it is a very bad idea.

Comment: That's what I originally had stated, but he apparently can't do that. So, hence my answer to solve today's problem and kick the can down the road. Because you are right, this is a very bad database design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'd got the solution by reducing 12 minutes from current date time and then selecting the time from reduced date time and comparing it with time.

Answer (score 0):

i think may be you need this: UPDATED

```
select * from tbl_booking where (date_created = CURDATE() AND time_created <= time(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))) OR (date_created < CURDATE()) order by booking_id desc
```

Comment: Posting an answer with variables in the query is likely to get voted down.  Even though this one is arguably "safe" if `$todaysdt` is generated in the script, we still can't be sure that it isn't user submitted; in which case this answer is not good practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @romaltandel. I'd done it using reducing 12 minutes from current date time and then selecting the time from reduced date time and comparing it with time.